# Could a personal jetpack flight legally occur over Australian cities?

Tags: australia

Have just been reading about the remarkable jetpack flight over Dubai, in the article [Flying over Dubai — and other places — with jetpacks](http://www.extremetech.com/extreme/205584-flying-over-dubai-and-other-places-with-jetpacks) (a YouTube of the incredible flight is available on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/Czy0pXRRZcs)).

My question is, what is the law regarding a similar flight over an Australian city?  (for example, flying over the Sydney Harbour Bridge and around the Centrepoint Tower)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the aircraft is allowed to operate in Australia, that the pilot was licensed, communications were to spec etc. then the answer is given in [designated Airspaces handbook](https://www.airservicesaustralia.com/aip/current/dah/dah.pdf).

Without going into details the airspace above Sydney is controlled and permission from Airservices Australia would be needed.

Comment: Might be worth expanding with this wiki entry. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airspace_class#Australia